# How to prove a statement about covering a set?

Tags: proof-writing

How to prove this statement?

"Any set of measure $0$ can be  covered by a sequence $((a_n,b_n))$ of intervals with $\sum (b_n-a_n) <\epsilon$."

It seems like this statement is correct by intuition. but I do not know how to prove it, could anyone help me in doing so?

Comment: It's the definition, is it not?

Comment: which definition?@Gae.S.

Comment: The definition of Lebesgue measure: the Lebesgue outer measure of a set is the greatest lower bound of those sums taken over all the coverings by intervals. If the set also happens to satisfy certain conditions, then we say that the set is measurable and that the aforementioned number is its Lebesgue measure.

Comment: And why the outer measure is the same as the measure in our case?@Gae.S.

Comment: Because I said so in my second sentence.

Comment: You should give us your definition of "measure 0".

Comment: I am confused I am using Royden 4th edition , "real analysis" and I do not remember where is the definition of "measure 0", could you please tell me if you know? @PaulFrost

Comment: I don't know the book, thus I can't help. But it seems that the **statement** in your question is not the definition.

Comment: @Emptymind Look at the definition of Lebesgue measure (presumably in the chapter that deals with Lebesgue measure, not the one that treats measure theory in general).